# Anyone have the Maplin N97DG bluetooth shield working?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, softwareserial

I went & impulse-bought a Maplin [Bluetooth shield](http://www.maplin.co.uk/search?text=Bluetooth+Shield+for+Arduino) yesterday.

It comes with a little tiny book containing [examples](http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=Bluetooth_Shield_for_Arduino), and uses the softwareserial library in these; I can load them, and get the Arduino <-> PC communication going OK, however there appears not to be a response from the bluetooth part of the device. The LED lights much as the booklet says it should. I did see it return some odd characters one time, just the once..

Given that the system appears to be alive, I don't want to give up & take it back; however the output from Google is not promising, and my trial to date isn't either - so I'm looking for positive news that this product does actually work for someone somewhere?

I'm using the built-in serial in the IDE to talk to it, not X-CTU as they suggest (as they don't do a Linux version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got mine working, in about 3 hours.

The first example I've never got working. The SAT+RESET worked first time... and I was then able to pair.

An easier module is the HC-05. That by default goes straight to discovery mode, and makes things alot easier.

I have more success with the serial monitor in Arduino studio, rather than X-CTU.

The point of the sheild is to prototype, or the shield you have to use in your production project. If you are doing the former, then there is little point in using the shield as you would have to change the code to fit the hardware.

It seems a thorough product, probably too involved.

Comment: Which Arduino board worked?

Comment: I have them both working on the Uno. Would you like me to put together my steps?

Comment: Actually, yes please, that would be useful - if I can have it working I may go re-purchase one!